# When will v3 comment updates be included in the client libraries?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api, google-api-dotnet-client

Comments for the v3 api was just released. We're using the .net client library and as far as I can tell the new comments changes are not included in the latest dlls.  Does anyone know when the changes will be included in the libraries?

I'm just trying to figure out if it's worth creating my own wrapper or not.  Thanks!

Comment: I think they're working on them as quickly as possible.... comments and comment threads were just added to the PHP library 6 hours ago. Hopefully we'll see the other major libraries get support over the next week or two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just uploaded the new v3 version to [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.YouTube.v3/1.9.0.1340).

I run the [NuGet publisher](https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client/tree/master/Tools/Google.Apis.NuGet.Publisher) once a week to update all Google.Apis packages. I already ran it this week, but with your request I just ran it again.

Comment: I wonder if that could be set to run automated?  Detect changes via the discovery api if one has changed run it.

Comment: Yeah, we could do that, but we have more important issues to solve first, anyway - feel free to create a new issue for that - https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client/issues :)

Comment: I checked v1.9.0.1340 and I don't see any v3 comment code in there.   Was it supposed to be there or will it be included in the next update?  Thanks!

Comment: That's the latest version of the API. Where is this feature documented in https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/youtube/v3/csharp/latest/ or in https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/?

Comment: @peleyal The feature is documented here https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads

Comment: @peleyal  It also looks like the resources are documented here https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/youtube/v3/csharp/latest/classGoogle_1_1Apis_1_1YouTube_1_1v3_1_1CommentThreadsResource.html

Comment: And the API doesn't? It's weird, because the documentation and the code is generated based on the discovery doc (in google api explorer), so if the documentation contains the feature the code should as well. Are you sure?

Comment: Argh... nuget was overwriting my updates with a local version.  It's there.  Thanks!